# Node Red how to set property msg.complete

Tags: node-red

I have a template node witch is a timer schedule produce this message

```
{"hour":5,"minute":5,"staus":false,"Tu":true,"We":false,"Sa":true}
```

I want to set many timers and send them in one message, for that I have added join function node witch has many option to create final message

> After a number of message parts
>
> After a timeout following the first message
>
> After a message with the msg.complete property set

to add more flexibility I have to use the third option, so I need to know how to set msg.complete in template code
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @knolleary suggests I have added flag last:(yes/no) to message to check if it is the last msg or not

```
{"hour":3,"minute":3,"staus":true,"Su":true,"Mo":true,"last":"no"}
```

then pass the message to `switch` node if it isn't last message then pass it directly to `join` node

else it is the last one then pass it to `change` node to set `msg.complete` then pass msg to `join` node 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `ui_template` node can only set the `msg.payload` property of the message it sends.

To set other properties, you'll need to add a `Change` node after the `ui_template` node.

If you want only certain messages from the `ui_template` node to have `msg.complete` set, then you'll need to add a flag in the `msg.payload` sent by the `ui_template` node which can checked for using a `Function` node to see if it should set `msg.complete` or not.

Comment: Thanks @knolleary ,  I got the general idea but it still little confused
how to check the msg.payload flag in Change node
could you please add little sample

Comment: The suggestion was to use the `function` node if you need to check the payload value